# Make file name containing date (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to save a file in a directory, and the filename should have this format:

```
iTerm Metrics Report Apr 12
```

i.e. the root file name "iTerm Metrics Report", followed by today's date formatted as three-letter month followed by day of the month.

How do I make such a filename?

Comment: `Please help me on this.` Sure :) What have you tried till now?

Comment: sFile = "iTerm metrics Report" & "" & Format(Date) & ".xls"
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\706849\My Documents\Metric Report\" & sFile

Answer (score 4):

> > > sFile = "iTerm metrics Report" & "" & Format(Date) & ".xls" ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Documents and Settings\706849\My Documents\Metric Report\" & sFile – Arul Servin 5 secs ago

Is this what you are trying?

```
sFile = "iTerm metrics Report " & Format(Date,"mmm yy") & ".xls"
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> > > Thank you...but am trying for Date (Apr 12) 12 is a date not a year...Please suggest me accordingly...thanks – Arul Servin 55 secs ago

In that case change the code to

```
sFile = "iTerm metrics Report " & Format(Date,"mmm dd") & ".xls"
```

Comment: Thank you...but am trying for Date (Apr 12) 12 is a date not a year...Please suggest me accordingly...thanks

Comment: sFile = "iTerm metrics Report " & Format(Date,"mmm DD") & ".xls"
is this correct?